# Why isn't `repr` calling `__repr__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class where a constructor argument is only used in `__init__` and therefore I didn't want to save it as a field, but I did want a nice `__repr__`. So I wrote something along these lines:

```py
from types import MethodType
class X:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__repr__ = MethodType(lambda _: f'X({x=})', self)
```

The `__repr__` method works fine:

```py
x = X(1)
x.__repr__()
```

Prints:

```
'X(x=1)'
```

But:

```py
repr(x)
```

Prints:

```
'<__main__.X object at 0x110f71810>'
```

Why isn't `repr` calling `__repr__`?

Comment: This doesn't work on built-in types.  `repr(x)` calls the internal hard-wired `__repr__` function.  This is documented somewhere, I just need to remember where.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Why does a dynamically added \_\_repr\_\_ method not override the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050557/python-why-does-a-dynamically-added-repr-method-not-override-the-default)

Comment: What you could do is `def __repr__(self): return self.__repr__()`. Which seems recursive, but is not, if you created an instance version of `__repr__` as you did

Comment: `repr()` calls the `__repr__()` method of the *class-type* object, not the instance object. See `Objects/object.h` function `PyObject_Repr()` in the CPython source code, where it returns that `<some object at address>` form when the *type* `tp_repr` is not set: `Py_TYPE(v)->tp_repr == NULL`

Comment: Though I did change the name so it doesn't look like a recursive call!